# Stored Procedure For Report

Tags: sql-server

In my stored procedure of sql server, below code is having issue

```
SELECT NULL AS s_empname
UNION
SELECT s_empname FROM ps_OFFICE
```

In this, I am not getting `NULL` as first option as it is not a string. If I pass it as:

```
SELECT ('NULL') AS ps_name
UNION
SELECT ps_name  ps_OFFICE
```

It is not working.

How can I update the first one in such a way that  `NULL` must be `s_empname` but must be shown in drop-down list of report as  'NULL' or 'No job'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`union` and `union all` do not guarantee the ordering of the results.  Only an `ORDER BY` clause does that.

So, you should use:

```
SELECT s_empname
FROM (SELECT NULL AS s_empname, 1 as priority
      UNION
      select s_empname, 2 from ps_OFFICE
     ) t
ORDER BY priority;
```

You should probably use `UNION ALL`, unless you intend to remove duplicates.

Comment: Null is showing as first option when i execute in sql server but In report NULL is not showing as first because it is NULL.SO instead of NULL if I want NULL to be shown as 'NoOfficeName' as first option then how can I amend above code.Thanks

Comment: Just change the `NULL` to `NoOfficeName`.